# Clear autocomplete suggestions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am using the vuetify `v-autocomplete` element. When a user types, a Get request is made to my server to fetch data to be displayed in the autocomplete drop down. The problem i'm facing is after a user selects a value the drop down menu, it still shows the results from the fetch requests.How can I clear the `:items` values. I tired removing `:cache-items="true"` but then when I select a item from the drop down menu it does not show in the input field. I'm trying to make something just like the Tags input field on stack overflow.

```
<v-autocomplete
    v-model="cityNames"
    :items="cities"
    outlined
    filled
    label="City"
    append-icon
    :loading="loadingCities"
    :search-input.sync="citysearch"
    item-text="name"
    dense
    :cache-items="true"
    hide-no-data
    item-value="id"
    chips
    @input="setCityId"
    @focus="cityFocused"
    return-object
>
```

Comment: what is your vuetify version ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 im using 2.2

Comment: we used the same, but here on mine my autocomplete hide its dropdown after use select item

Comment: @Qonvex620, maybe I did not explain right, After I select the drop down does away. But when I go to enter another word in the input field the previous suggestions show again. I dont want the previous suggestions showing when I haven't entered any text

Comment: it is not because of your search.sync ?

Comment: @Qonvex620 when I focus on the input field to start typing thr next work there is no request made to my server. But still the old suggestions show